# How to load/read data from cassandra by partition by partition using java8?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spring-boot , datastax-java-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.1.jar and java8.

> I have scenario where I need to read/load the data from C* table, but
>   this table might have million of records.
>
> I need to load this data from C* table, is there anyway in
>   java/spring-boot using datastax-java-cassandra-connector API I can
>   pull the data partition by partition?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table`? the java driver (that it uses) returns an iterator that lazily fetches data as iterating through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while `select * from table` may work, more effective way could be to read data by token ranges with query like `select * from table where token(part_key) > beginRange and token(part_key) <= endRange`. The Spark Cassandra connector works the same way - it gets the list of all available token ranges, and then fetch data from every token range, but send it directly to the node that holds this token range (as opposite to `select * from table` that retrieves all data via coordinator node).

You need to be careful in calculation of the token boundaries, especially for begin & end of the full range. You can find an [example of the Java code in my repository](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/TokenRangesScan.java) (it's too long to paste it here).

Comment: how information about ranges is stored is version dependent, and although you can pull it from system tables, it's better to get it from `Metadata` class that knows how to read it for different versions of Cassandra.

Comment: that schema works also - it's really heavily dependent on your business requirements